# NoSuchFieldException:driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, properties, properties-file

I'm running my regression and smoke tests as usual, but in the middle of the process the process it self fails. And i receive the above error. I updated my chrome driver, as well as chrome itself. But i keep getting the same error, this is the first time i get such an issue, and i have reviewed the code but i can't find any reasonable mistake . Any suggestions?

Find part of my base code here...

```
public class base {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    public  Properties prop;

    public WebDriver initializeDriver() throws IOException 
    {
        prop = new Properties();
            //FileInputStream System.getProperty("user.dir")
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/main/java/resources/data.properties");
        prop.load(file);
        String browserName = prop.getProperty("browser");
        //Field field = Class.getField("driver");
        //String browserName = System.getProperty("browser");
        System.out.println(browserName);
        if (browserName.equals("Chrome")){
            //Execute
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/lisandrosilva/Documents/Drivers/chromedriver 6");
            //ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        if(browserName.equals("headless")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/lisandrosilva/Documents/Drivers/chromedriver 5");
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                    options.addArguments("--headless");

                    options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
                    driver = new ChromeDriver(options); 
            }            
        else if (browserName.equals("Safari")) {
            //Execute
            //driver = new SafariDriver();
        }
        else if (browserName.equals("FireFox")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/Users/lisandrosilva/Documents/Drivers/geckodriver 3");
                        driver = new FirefoxDriver();   
            //Execute
                // driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }
```

Comment: Please clean up your code to make it more readable and add any stack traces you see

Comment: Also point out which line produces the error.

Answer (score 0):

### NoSuchFieldException

[NoSuchFieldException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchFieldException.html) indicates that the class doesn't have a field of a specified name.

If this error is happening in the mid of your tests, probably your program is accessing the wrong file. I would suggest to rename the properties file as `myProp.properties` instead of `data.properties` and execute your tests.

Comment: Hmm, seems that make things worse, no test actually runs with file as myProp.properties...

Comment: @LisandroFernando So possibly you weren't using your own `data.properties` but were using the cached `data.properties`

Comment: ok, sir do you have any possible solution for cached data.properties? I'm calling my driver static to not fill the browser memory.

Comment: I have also open chrome browser manually, went to settings and deleted all caches and cookies but the issue remains... Any ideas?

Comment: I just found out why i had such an issue. It was a TestNG listener, i had this method getDeclaredField that made the regression fail at running time. Instead i used getField method which is taken as a super class. Thanks for the attention

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue and it got resolved now as [Lisandro Fernando](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13989490/lisandro-fernando) mentioned in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63076875/nosuchfieldexceptiondriver/65758447#comment111718236_63077620).

Used `getField` method instead of `getDeclaredField` method.